# How do I Bubble Sort a linked list?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a linked list and sort it by Bubble Sort. I succeeded to create the linked list, but when I am trying to Bubble Sort it, some accidents occur and I do not know the problem. What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//the struct of LinkedList
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node * pNext;
}NODE,*PNODE;

PNODE createList();//Creat one LinkedList
int lengthList(PNODE pHead);//get the length of LinkedList
void sortList(PNODE);//bubble sort

int main()
{
    int length;
    PNODE pHead=NULL;
    pHead=createList();
    sortList(pHead);
    return 0;
}
//Create LinkedList
PNODE createList()
{
    int i,n;
    int val;
    PNODE pHead=(PNODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if(pHead==NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to create!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    pHead->pNext=NULL;
    PNODE pTail=pHead;
    printf("please input the length of the LinkedList:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("number %d is:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&val);
        PNODE pNew=(PNODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        if(pNew==NULL)
        {
            printf("failed to create\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        pNew->data=val;
        pTail->pNext=pNew;
        pNew->pNext=NULL;
        pTail=pNew;
    }
    return pHead;
}
//get the length of LinkedList
int lengthList(PNODE pHead)
{
    int i=0;
    PNODE p=pHead->pNext;
    while(p!=NULL)
{
        i++;
        p=p->pNext;
    }
    return i;
}
//bubble sort
void sortList(PNODE pHead)
{
    int i,j,t,len;
    PNODE p,q;
    len=lengthList(pHead);
    p=pHead->pNext;
    for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<len-i;j++)
        {
            q=p->pNext;
            if( p->data > q->data)
            {
                t=p->data;
                p->data=q->data;
                q->data=t;
            }
            p=q;//here may be the error
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: @rootkea: Please don't suggest edits where you move all `{` into a new line. If the OP prefers to put `{` on the same line and they do it consistently, then please leave the code as it is.

Comment: What kind of "accidents" occur? Please be aware that Stack Overflow is no debugging service. You have to provide more details on what you expect and what you actually get. Also please read: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @honk: Got that! Then may be I should move `main` function's `{` on the same line as `int main()` for consistency's sake.

Comment: Thank you,@rootkea,@honk.  The compiler said no error,but when i am running it,the program stopped accidently.

Comment: @rootkea: I just did that for you. But, please don't suggest edits where you just propose to move a few parentheses. Please focus on posts that need overall edits and fix as much as you can. That would help SO most. If you get > 2k rep, you can also do minor edit, because then you no longer bind the time of reviewers for that.

Comment: First of all *bubble sorting* a linked list is about the least efficient way you can sort a list of any size. That being said, there are many examples of bubble sort for arrays on this site. Where they iterate (e.g. `for (i = 1, i < n-1....) for (j = 0; ...)` you will need to iterate over your list. e.g. `list *iter = list; while (iter->next) ... compare iter, iter->next; ... iter=iter->next;` for the next comparison. You can set up 2 `iter` type variables and basically recreate your bubble sort on a list that way.

Comment: @eric: You have `malloc` in your code, but no `free`. So, you produce a memory leak. Please also learn how to clean up allocated memory when you no longer need it.

Comment: @honk:Now I freed pTail,there is no longer memory leak.but problem still exists.

Comment: Voting to close as why isn't this code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running off the end of your list in sortList

```
p=pHead->pNext;
for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<len-i;j++)
    {
        q=p->pNext;
        ....
        p=q;//here may be the error
    }
}
```

Bug 1) Your list is only `len` long but you are attempting to advance `p` to `p->pNext` far more then `len` times.

Bug 2) pHead does not need to be a full NODE - it's just a PNODE pointer. You never use its data field. You should have pHead point to the first node in the list, and then start your iteration at pHead rather than pHead->pNext.

Bug 3) You never clean up your memory allocations.

Comment: Thank you,@Airsource Ltd,awesome!

Comment: Bug 1)I have solved the problem.                                                                              Bug 2)pHead is only a pointer,there is no actually data.                                  Bug 3)I will clean up my memory allocations.                                                     Thank you,@Airsource Ltd,this is the 1st time that i am trying to ask question here,and get the good answer,thank you again,i will walk around here usually.

Comment: Bug 2), yes I see. But then pHead does not need to be a NODE... I've modified my answer. BTW by far the simplest way to find issues is to run the code in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

As @Airsource pointed out the bugs, keep in mind most of them are caused because of poor designing choice of your program. Try to do it like below & you will run into less errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct _Node{
    int data;
    struct _Node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct {
    Node* headPtr;
    Node* tailPtr;
    unsigned size;
}List;

static void create_node(List* list, int element) {
    if (list->headPtr == NULL) {
        // List is empty
        list->headPtr = (Node* )malloc(sizeof(Node));
        list->headPtr->data = element;
        list->headPtr->next = 0;
        list->tailPtr = list->headPtr;
        list->size++;
    }else{
        // List was already populated
        Node* temp = (Node* )malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp->data = element;
        temp->next = 0;
        list->tailPtr->next = temp;
        list->tailPtr = temp;
        list->size++;
    }
}

void create_list(List* list, int length){
    int ele;
    int i;
    list->headPtr = list->tailPtr = 0;
    list->size = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &ele);
        create_node(list, ele);
    }
}

void print_list(List* list){
    Node* loop = list->headPtr;
    while(loop){
        printf("%d ", loop->data);
        loop = loop->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


 int main(){
    List* list;
    int n;
    printf("Enter the length of the list: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    create_list(list, n);
    print_list(list);
    bubble_sort(list);
    print_list(list);
    if (cleanup(list))
        printf("Memory rescued!!\n");
    else
        printf("OOPS!! Error\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Moreover, you can get the size anytime just by `list->size`. No need for separate function to do that.

Finally to sort it using bubble sort you could do something like this below

```
void bubble_sort(List* list) {
    int i, j;
    Node* first, *second;
    int temp;
    first = list->headPtr;
    second = list->headPtr->next;
    for (i = 0; i < list->size - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < list->size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (first->data > second->data){
                temp = first->data;
                first->data = second->data;
                second->data = temp;
            }
            first = second;
            second = second->next;
        }
        first = list->headPtr;
        second = list->headPtr->next;
    }
}
```

and for cleanup you do this

```
bool cleanup(List* list) {
    Node* curr = list->headPtr;
    Node* nxt = list->headPtr->next;
    while(nxt){
        free(curr);
        curr = nxt;
        nxt = curr->next;
    }
    list->headPtr = list->tailPtr = 0;
    list->size = 0;
    return !nxt ? true: false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,@Mayukh Sarkar,I will try!That will be more concise!

Comment: you should upvote both @Airsource and me if you find the solutions interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of bugs in your program. I will address them one by one:

1. Line 28  `PNODE pHead=(PNODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));`
   Here you are allocating a memory and creating a node before checking if n>0 or not.
2. Line 36  `printf("please input the length of the LinkedList:");`
   Now up to this point you have created a one node, `head` node which has *no* value in it (so contains garbage)

In effect your `createList()` creates a linked list with `n+1` nodes instead of `n` and the `head->value` contains garbage.

Solution:

```
printf("please input the length of the LinkedList:");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    PNODE pNew = (PNODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if(pNew == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to create!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    scanf("%d", &val);
    pNew->data = val;
    pNew->pNext = NULL;

    if (!i)
        pHead = pNew;
    else
        pTail->pNext = pNew;
    pTail = pNew;      
}

return pHead;
```

3. Line 59 `PNODE p=pHead->pNext;`
   Here you are counting nodes starting from the second node (leaving out `head`). No wonder you will get `length` as `n` as you have created a linked list of length `n+1` in your `createList()`

Imagine what if `n = 0` and thus `pHead = NULL`?
Then this line will result in `SegFault`.

Solution:
change `PNODE p=pHead->pNext;` to `PNODE p = pHead;`

4. Line 73 `p=pHead->pNext;`
   Here you will start sorting excluding the first node, `head` node.
   Also this should be inside the outter `for` and outside of the inner `for` to reset the `p` to first node for each pass.
5. Line 76 `for(j=0;j<len-i;j++)`
   Here j must be less than `len - 1 - i` as in pass 1 (`i = 0`) in the worst case j will be equal to `len-1` for `j < len-i`, where `p` will point to the last node of linked list and `q` will be NULL as `q = p -> pNext`. Which will make `q->data` to result in `SegFault`.

To summarise, your sort routine is producing `SegFault` in the very first Pass and even if it didn't (by properly adjusting the loop-terminating expression in inner `for`) the outer `for` loop is contributing nothing towards the sorting except increasing the time complexity.

Solution:

```
for(i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
{
    p = pHead;
    for(j = 0; j < len - 1 - i; j++)
    {
        q = p -> pNext;
        if(p->data > q->data)
        {
            t = p -> data;
            p -> data = q -> data;
            q -> data = t;
        }
        p = q;
    }
}
```

A question:
How are you checking whether element have been sorted or not?
A `printList()` routine would have been helpful in spotting the above bugs.

**"Always verify whether you correctly stored the input or not by explicitly printing the same before processing it!"**